# Game Theory: Prisoner Dilemma calculating the odds

Tags: linear-algebra

How can you by using a matrix, find the optimal strategies for each player in the prisoner dilemma, and calculate the odds of them choosing that option?

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║         ║   Confess  ║   Deny      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Confess ║ 3y/3y      ║ 10y/1y      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Deny    ║ 1y/10y     ║ 2y/2y       ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

The column player confesses with the probability of P and denies with the probability of P-1

When I try to calculate the probability for the row player, I do: $$3p+1(1-p)=10p+2(1-p)$$

However then I get: $$P= -1/6$$
Which doesnt work. So I wonder what did I do wrong?

Comment: That's certainly a weird presentation of the prisoner's dilemma, with deny/deny being worse for the prisoners than confess/confess.

Comment: oh sorry, I put them in the wrong order

Answer (score 1):

I think you  are assuming that a mixed strategy exists, that is, some probability that the Row player is indifferent between Confess and Deny. (That  is what the equation in your question is assuming.) Let $q$ be that probability.
then the row player seeks to choose $q$ to maximize:
$$U=q[3p+(1-p)1]+(1-q)[10p+2(1-p)].$$
$$=-q(6p+1)+8p+2.$$

Maximize by taking the derivative
$$\frac{du}{dq} =-(6p+1).$$
But, as you point out, unless $p$ has the impossible value-1/6, the derivative does  not equal zero. So the maximum value is a corner solution, where, since the derivative is negative, $q$ takes on it's maximum value, which, for a probability, is 1.

That is the famous solution to Prisoner's Dilemma, that whatever the other player does, your best (Dominant) strategy is to confess.